# Flutter: Convert Base64 String image url to File and use it in FileImage or related widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

I've tried this way, and use it in `FileImage` but haven't found a rally point

```
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(imageBase64);
File file = File.fromRawPath(bytes);
```

`imageBase64` is the image url that has been encode.

The point of this thing is, i want to use it in `FileImage` or another widget image file but i don't want this image is saved to device and upload this file to the attachments file Rest API

can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do once you have the bytes is to show the image, then you can use `Image.memory`.

```
var imageWidget = Image.memory(bytes);
```

OTOH If you're trying to upload the image, you don't need to convert it into file. You can use bytes directly assuming you can't upload it using base64 enconding. Package [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

...

```
//create multipart using filepath, string or bytes
MultipartFile multipartFile = MultipartFile.fromBytes(
  'file',
  byteData,
  filename: fileName,
);

//add multipart to request
request.files.add(multipartFile);
var response = await request.send();
```

Comment: but i have to convert it to File too

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question but you said that wanted a `FileImage` or another widget....  `Image.memory` returns a widget. What you're trying to do with that @Miko?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an UintList8 you can use MemoryImage(bytes).

```
Uint8List bytes = base64.decode(imageBase64);
Image(image: MemoryImage(bytes));
```

Comment: but i have to convert it to File too

Comment: Do you want a FileImage that loads an image from a file or an `io.File` that is the binary file itself?